# How do I make a sine wave without using an infinitely-increasing time value as input?

Tags: c++, trigonometry, timestep

I have a basic understanding of [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) generation. The problem I am facing is that as the input parameter for time gets larger, my sine wave falls apart and starts to look really ugly.

I'd like to calculate a sine wave without depending on an ever increasing time value. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could restart your time value every 2pi:

```
if(time > 2*pi)
  time -= 2*pi;
```

If is still okay to increase your time variable infinitely but the input for the sine is to large, just use `fmod(time, 2*pi)`.

Comment: thank you, using fmod worked. It seemed to keep the values between 2*pi. Quick question, what does fmod do? I read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fmod.htm it says fmod returns the remainder but I don't get why it works.

Comment: basically it returns r in the equation `x = n*y + r` where x and y are the inputs and n is an integer.

Comment: The reason you hit the issue you did is that as floating point numbers get larger, they lose accuracy.  For instance if you start at zero and add one to a floating point number in an infinite loop, there will come a point where adding the 1 results in the same value (ie will have no effect)

Comment: @ratchetfreak so is fmod like the modulus operation?